# Is it possible to use the third party plugins or modules which feature or plugins are not available in Nativescript official plugins?

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

Is it possible to use any third parties plugins which features are not avail in nativescript official plugins.

Like Angular-trix for angularjs-
"http://sachinchoolur.github.io/angular-trix/"

If it is possible means how should i achieve?

Thank you for reading, looking forward to reading your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a crosspost with https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/can-i-use-non-nativescript-specific-third-party-plugins/2054/2, so here's my duped answer as well:

Usually the answer is yes, but in this specific case, according to their GitHub account this library is for Angular 1 - which is not supported by NativeScript.

Comment: Thank you @Eddy Verbruggen.